# How to Repeat Saving my Powerpoint file every 5 minutes?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've been wanting to write a macro to automatically save my powerpoint file every 5 minutes. Can anyone help?

I know there's an auto-save built-in but that's only good for auto recover. I'm attempting to have this ppt being saved every 5 mins so that other users using it at the same time will see the updates come in (using Office 365).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to do this with a simple macro, but you might be able to make it work with an add-in.

The add-in would:

- Trap events, specifically the SelectionChanged event.
- Every time the event fires, the event handling code compares the current time to the time it last fired (stored in a static variable).
- If more than x minutes have elapsed since the event last fired, saves the presentation and resets the last-fired time.

If the event never fires during a session, it means that nothing changed, so no real reason to save.

A further refinement: before or after checking the time difference, check the presentation's .Saved property. If True, then nothing has changed in the presentation, so again, no reason to save.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but most answers I've seen regarding saving in intervals use the OnTime method. This isn't actually available in PowerPoint, so I'm not actually sure that what you're wanting to do is possible.